# create log file ssh (only ssh)

Tags: ssh, log-files

I use ubuntu 10.04, contained ssh. I want to create a log file that stores all the activity on ssh (only ssh). Like in `/var/log/auth.log` but only for ssh. Like`/var/log/ssh.log`.

So, file ssh.log will saving all records of the client when using ssh to a remote server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reconfigure your syslog daemon.

OpenSSH just sends the log messages to the syslog daemon with the `SyslogFacility` and `LogLevel` which is defined in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

In which file the log is written ist just a configuration thing of your syslog-daemon.

Comment: which part to edit in `/etc/ss/sshd_config`?

Comment: none, as mgabriel answered, `You need to reconfigure your syslog daemon` and not change `sshd_config`. The options in SSH config file are only to specify the level of logging.